# using pyteserract 0.1.5 i get the following error after i use print image_to_string(img)what file is it not able to find?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm new to coding in python .i am using Pillow .  The following is the code:

```
    >>> from PIL import Image
    >>> from pytesseract import*
    >>> img=Image.open("C:\image.jpg")
    >>> print image_to_string(img)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
        print image_to_string(img)
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 142, in         image_to_string
    config=config)
      File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 75, in run_tesseract
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
    WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: By the way, 4 spaces before the beginning of a line makes a block of code.

Comment: I got that same error when I didn't have Tesseract installed. Did you install Tesseract? Pytesseract calls Tesseract by command line. You can download an installer from: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Downloads

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham can anyone suggest me how i install pytesseract 0.1.5 on ubuntu 16.04 on a user account?

Comment: @Prashanth Prakash  can anyone suggest me how i install pytesseract 0.1.5 on ubuntu 16.04 on a user account?

Comment: @all can anyone suggest me how i install pytesseract 0.1.5 on ubuntu 16.04 on a user account?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is late, but I ran into the same problem and error message, so I'm posting this to help anyone else who encounters the problem.

The reason this isn't working is because Tesseract is not installed. Tesseract is an executable file and Pytesseract is just a Python interface for it. Pytesseract is trying to run Tesseract from the command line, but Windows is not able to find an executable file called Tesseract. An installer for Tesseract can be downloaded from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Downloads.

If you already have Tesseract installed, check if you can run it from the command line (just type "tesseract"). If it doesn't work, then you will need to add the executable's folder to your path variable (this should be taken care of for you if you use the installer).

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter the same situation, it is just because the priority of your system account, so don't save you py and image file in C disk, move to the other disk, It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running while using Pytesseract. It is not working because of the following reasons:

1. Since the image is in C:\, maybe you do not have access rights. Try running the Python IDLE or cmd in Administrator mode.
2. The Tesseract is not installed. The pytesseract is just a python interface. You need to download and install the exe. You can download it from [here](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_tesseract-ocr-alt/downloads/tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe/).
3. Add this code `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'` or you could add your path upto the exe file for teserract in your python script. Then try running.

Answer (score 0):

write your path like this:

```
img=Image.open(r"C:\image.jpg")
```

surely it will open the image.

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely caused by permission requirements. Without getting too into users and permissions, essentially python isn't being run as administrator, so it doesn't have access to `C:\image.jpg`, because C:\ is restricted.

To not have these restrictions in place move the image to your `Documents` folder then change the opening to `img=Image.open(os.environ[USERPROFILE]+"\\Documents\\image.jpg")`. Your `Documents` folder doesn't have the same restrictions, so it is better to place your test image there.

`os.environ` stores some useful directory information, such as where the user profile is.  On my computer, my username is `IronManMark20` so the path to the profile is `C:\Users\IronManMark20\`. `os.environ[USERPROFILE]`  correctly gets that information. For more on the very useful os library look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).  **NOTE**:literally enter "USERPROFILE" not your username! So I wouldn't enter `IronManMark20`, I would enter `USERPROFILE`.

Then I added `\\Documents\\image.jpg` to make the rest of path. Note the double backslashes, which in python means that there should be a single backslash because of [character escapes](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). It has always been better to use this instead of single `\`  in my experience.

Comment: i tried it but now i am getting the following error :
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Python27/test.py", line 4, in <module>
        img=Image.open(os.environ['Prashanth     prakash']+"\\Documents\\phototest.tif")
      File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
        return self.data[key.upper()]
    KeyError: 'PRASHANTH PRAKASH'

Comment: Sorry, did you enter `PRASHANTH PRAKASH` where I put USERPROFILE? Your supposed to literally put `USERPROFILE`. I'll change my answer to reflect that and make it clearer.

Comment: i tried this again but it says that USERPROFILE is not defined .

Comment: Could you `import os` and look at `os.environ`? It should give an array of OS data. You can also just hard-code your path. (So for mine it would be "C:\\Users\\IronManMark20\\Documents\\img.jpg"

Comment: Ah, also, as a correction, os.environ is a dict. So when I say "USERNAME" you enter `"USERNAME"` quotes and all.

Comment: @PrashanthPrakash what about this answer is incorrect? Is this not working for you?